# How do i create a task that contains multiple videos?

Tags: data-annotations, cvat

Now the system creates a different task for every video, and I want related videos to be different jobs of the same task. How can I do that?

I have multiple videos of the same people from different dates, on some dates more than one video.
I want different videos to be jobs of the same task.